# Defining function using loop for numpy.linspace

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I am a beginner at programming, I am using python 3.0

I am given a function 
h(x) = 1 if 0.1<= x <= 0.3 , or = 0 otherwise

I have

```
L = 1
N=200    
x = numpy.linspace(0,L,N)
```

I want to define  a function for h(x) that loops through the values of x and returns 1 or 0 based on the conditions given above

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.logical_and` and `astype`:

```
np.logical_and(x >= 0.1, x <= 0.3).astype(int)
```

---

Plot showing the behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension as following. This is basically using a combination of for loop, if-else statement in a one liner. Here, you use `if` condition to check if `x` is between 0.1 and 0.3 and saves 1 in the `hx` otherwise 0.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
L = 1
N=200    
x = numpy.linspace(0,L,N)
hx = [1 if 0.1 <= i <= 0.3 else 0 for i in x] # list comprehension
plt.plot(x, hx)
plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('h(x)', fontsize=18)
```

**Alternative vectorised approach** : Here `(x>=0.1) & (x<=0.3)` returns the indices where x fulfills the conditions and for those indices, evaluate `hx` to 1. Here you initialize `hx` to be all zeros.

```
hx = numpy.zeros(N)
hx[(x>=0.1) & (x<=0.3)] = 1
```

**Using it as a function**

```
def get_hx(x):
    # hx = numpy.zeros(N)
    # hx[(x>=0.1) & (x<=0.3)] = 1
    hx = [1 if 0.1 <= i <= 0.3 else 0 for i in x]
    return hx

hx = get_hx(x)
```

[image]